# Determine the values of a for which the following system of linear equations has no solutions, a unique solution, or infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not quite sure if I am doing this equation right. I am still a bit stumped how to solve for a. If I could have some guide towards the right direction that would be greatly appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtsqU.jpg)

$$2_x1+2x_2+4x_3  =  −6$$
$$3x_1+5x_2+6x_3  =  −3$$
$$3x_1+4x_2+ax_3  =  −5$$

Comment: You should type at least the initial system.

Comment: I guess you made a mistake while copying the 5 below. You wrote it as a 3

Answer (score -1):

$$\det\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 2 & 4 \\
 3 & 5 & 6 \\
 3 & 4 & a \\
\end{array}
\right|=4a-24$$
if $\det\ne 0$ then for Cramer's Theorem there is one and only one solution.

If $\det=0\to a = 6$ then the matrix becomes
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 2 & 4 \\
 3 & 5 & 6 \\
 3 & 4 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and its range is $2$.
While the completed matrix
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 2 & 2 & 4 & -6 \\
 3 & 5 & 6 & -3 \\
 3 & 4 & 6 & -5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
has rank $3$. Thus the system is impossible for this [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem#Formal_statement).